# Do these two functions both create collections of Classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've written a piece of code in C# that can create a collection of Classes and stores them all in an array. I know that code works and does the job fine and I've been using it to store results from a database to display.

Now I need to replicate the same behaviour using VB.NET and after some Google-ing it appears I've found the closest solution.

I've run the C#code through a translator (C# to VB.NET) but that did not give me the correct result and produced an error when placed inside my collection class.

Here's the code:-
C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KnightOwl_BusinessLogic.DataObjects.Animal_Module
{
    public class AnimalCollection : Collection<Animal>
    {
        public Animal[] ToArray()
        {
            Animal[] array = new Animal[this.Count];
            this.CopyTo(array, 0);
            return array;
        }
    }

}
```

VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Namespace DataModels

    Public Class VisitorListCollection

        Public VisitorList As New Collection

        Private Sub addVisitor()
            Dim tempVisitor As New Visitor()
            VisitorList.Add(tempVisitor)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

It all builds with no errors but I'm just not convinced it going to be doing the same job.

Comment: That's not the same code. I can't imagine any translator turning that c# snippet into that vb snippet.

Comment: These two pieces of code seems to be totally unrelated. Could you clarify your problem? At least for me, it's not clear at all

Comment: Basically I need the VB code to be doing the same as the C# code but with Visitors instead of Animals - I have a visitor class for a singular visitor but am trying to put something place for when multiple visitors need to be displayed instead of one - I've managed to do this in C# using the above code but not in VB.NET - and I was wondering if the VB.NET code above would create a collection of of the Visitor class?

Comment: In your first sample, the Collection class already has a [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx). Why are you creating your own?  Your two sample are very different, one get an array, the other add to a list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# code creates a fixed size array of items. Your VB.Net code creates a list of items. They are both 'collections' but the VB.Net example creates a collection that you can add more items to. This may or may not be what you want.